# What does Gramsci mean by "leaders of the II and II-~"?

Tags: marxism, politics

A friend of mine who has been reading Antonio Gramsci's Selection from Prison Notebooks is struggling to find out what ***II-~*** means in the following paragraph:

"If there are still people at the enlarged meeting of the Executive who have not grasped the fact that the tactic of the united front will help us to overthrow ***the leaders of II and II-~ Internationals***, these people should have an extra number of popular lectures and talks read to them."

I guess these Roman numerals refer to ***the Second and Two-and-a-half International (or the Vienna International)***.

Please let me know what you think.

Comment: Yes, see [Second International](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_International)

Comment: Any idea how this II-~ is read in English?

Answer (score 2):

Your guess is correct.

See Antonio Gramsci, *Selections form The Prison Notebooks* (Quintin Hoare & Geoffrey Nowell editors), Introduction, page xlviii:

> "the **II** and **II 1/2** Internationals"

that fits well with what is [usually called](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_International#Attempted_re-establishment_and_successor_organizations_(1918%E2%80%931923)):

"the International Working Union of Socialist Parties (IWUSP) (Second and a half International or Two-and-a-half International)".

Comment: Thanks very much.